# Making a Weighted Grading Scale in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Create a program that will calculate a student’s grade in a class that uses a weighted grade scale.
I have to be able to manually enter each Quiz, Test, Participation, and Project Grade. It's my first year learning Python at all, and it is my first language! Thanks for the help!
*Edit: Right now the code is giving me this:
"
John Doe 
John Doe , You made a function letter_grade at 0x7f4424330dd0"*

```
name="John Doe"
print(name)

#Entering Particiaption Grade and Weight
def Participation(Participation1):
  Participation1= int(input())
  participation_average=int(input(Participation1/1))
  return participation_average

def ParticipationW(ParticipationWeight):
  ParticipationWeight = int(input())
  return ParticipationWeight

#Entering Quiz Grades and Weight
def Quiz(Quiz1, Quiz2, Quiz3, Quiz4, Quiz5, Quiz6):
  Quiz1 = int(input())
  Quiz2 = int(input())
  Quiz3 = int(input())
  Quiz4 = int(input())
  Quiz5 = int(input())
  Quiz6 = int(input())
  quiz_average=int(input((Quiz1+Quiz2+Quiz3+Quiz4+Quiz5+Quiz6)/6))
  return quiz_average

def QuizW(QuizWeight):
  QuizWeight = int(input())
  return QuizWeight

#Projects

def Project(Project1, Project2, Project3, Project4, Project5, Project6):
  Project1 = int(input())
  Project2 = int(input())
  Project3 = int(input())
  Project4 = int(input())
  Project5 = int(input())
  Project6 = int(input())
  project_average=int(input((Project1+Project2+Project3+Project4+Project5+Project6)/6))
  return project_average

def ProjectW(ProjectWeight):
  ProjectWeight = int(input())
  return ProjectWeight

#Enter Test Grades and Variables

def Test(Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4):
  Test1 = int(input())
  Test2 = int(input())
  Test3 = int(input())
  Test4 = int(input())
  test_average=int(input((Test1+Test2+Test3+Test4)/4))
  return test_average

def TestW(TestWeight):
  TestWeight = int(input())
  return TestWeight


def letter_grade(FinalGrade):
  FinalGrade=int(input((Participation * ParticipationW) + (Quiz * QuizW) + (Project * ProjectW) + (Test* TestW)))
  if FinalGrade >= 90:
    return "You made a A!"
  elif FinalGrade >= 80:
    return "You made a B!"
  elif FinalGrade >= 70:
    return "You made a C!"
  elif FinalGrade >= 60:
    return "You made a D!"
  else:
    return "Sorry, you failed."

print(name, ", You made a", letter_grade, ".")
```

This is what he has given us so far:

Enter Student Name:

Please enter the total possible quiz grade:60

Please enter quiz weight in decimal form:.15

Please enter the first quiz grade:10

Please enter the second quiz grade:5

Please enter the third quiz grade:6

Please enter the fourth quiz grade:7

Please enter the fifth quiz grade:10

Please enter the sixth quiz grade:9

Please enter the total possible Participation grade:100

Please enter participation weight in decimal form:.05

Please enter the Participation grade:100

Please enter the total possible project grade:600

Please enter project weight in decimal form:.50

Please enter the first project grade:100

Please enter the second project grade:100

Please enter the third project grade:90

Please enter the fourth project grade:80

Please enter the fifth project grade:80

Please enter the sixth project grade:50

Please enter the total possible test grade:400

Please enter test weight in decimal form:.30

Please enter the first test grade:100

Please enter the second test grade:90

Please enter the third test grade:80

Please enter the fourth test grade:50

Jon Doe's grades are:

Overall Quiz Grade: 11.75

Overall Participation Grade: 5.0

Overall Project Grade: 41.66666666666667

Overall Test Grade: 24.0

Final Grade: 82.41666666666667

Your Grade: B

Comment: What is your problem exactly? (other than needing to get your homework done)

Comment: @Grismar I need to go through and be able to put in each grade and weight. Right now when I run the program all I recieve is "John Doe
John Doe , You made a <function letter_grade at 0x7f4424330dd0> ." I don't know where the problem lies at.

Comment: You should have provided that error message as part of the question, since that's really your question: why am I getting this error message? You're getting that error message because you're printing the function, not the result of calling the function. Compare `print(lettergrade)` vs `print(lettergrade())`. Also, you've defined the function to have `FinalGrade` as a parameter, but you're defining that value in the function itself, so that seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Here is your answer dear all the best and welcome to Python`**

### Code

```
name=input("Enter your name:")
    def grade():
      #Entering Particiaption Grade and Weight
      Participation1= int(input("Entering Particiaption Grade :"))
      participation_average=Participation1
      ParticipationWeight = int(input("Entering Particiaption Weight:"))
      #Entering Quiz Grades and Weight
      Quiz1 = int(input("Enter Quiz 1  Grades:"))
      Quiz2 = int(input("Enter Quiz 2  Grades:"))
      Quiz3 = int(input("Enter Quiz 3  Grades:"))
      Quiz4 = int(input("Enter Quiz 4  Grades:"))
      Quiz5 = int(input("Enter Quiz 5  Grades:"))
      Quiz6 = int(input("Enter Quiz 6  Grades:"))
      quiz_average=(Quiz1+Quiz2+Quiz3+Quiz4+Quiz5+Quiz6)/6
      QuizWeight = int(input("Enter Quiz weight:"))
      #Projects
      Project1 = int(input("Enter Project 1  Grades:"))
      Project2 = int(input("Enter Project 2  Grades:"))
      Project3 = int(input("Enter Project 3  Grades:"))
      Project4 = int(input("Enter Project 4  Grades:"))
      Project5 = int(input("Enter Project 5  Grades:"))
      Project6 = int(input("Enter Project 6  Grades:"))
      project_average=(Project1+Project2+Project3+Project4+Project5+Project6)/6
      ProjectWeight = int(input("Enter Project Weight:"))
      #Enter Test Grades and Variables
      Test1 = int(input("Enter Test 1  Grades:"))
      Test2 = int(input("Enter Test 2  Grades:"))
      Test3 = int(input("Enter Test 3  Grades:"))
      Test4 = int(input("Enter Test 4  Grades:"))
      test_average=(Test1+Test2+Test3+Test4)/4
      TestWeight = int(input("Enter Test Weight:"))
      FinalGrade=(participation_average*   ParticipationWeight) + (quiz_average*  QuizWeight) + ( project_average * ProjectWeight) + (test_average* TestWeight)
      print("Dear ",name,",")
      if FinalGrade >= 90:
        print("You made a A!")
      elif FinalGrade >= 80:
        print( "You made a B!")
      elif FinalGrade >= 70:
        print("You made a C!")
      elif FinalGrade >= 60:
        print("You made a D!")
      else:
        print("Sorry, you failed.")
    grade()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering how to be able to insert the grades! I am really looking forward to learning it more!

Comment: I did upvote but it will not show yet because my reputation is below 15! It recorded it but it won't let it show! Sorry!

Comment: It's okay no worries